# Outlook addin Disable the removal of addin

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, add-in

I am using visual studio 2005 and outlook 2007 .

I would like to set a master password on outlook such that user will be able to disable my addin only if the correct master password is entered.The user should not be able to disable or remove the addin  unless the master password is provided.Can this be done... upto what I researched I could not find any thing that could prevent the addin being disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 2007 addins can be Native or VSTO.
Both relay on a key in the registry, that tells Outlook to load them.

There is no way for you to force Outlook to load an addin, unless the user is not an admin on the local machine - on that case, you can register your addin in the HKLM key, so it will be reloaded every time, even if the user removed it from within Outlook settings page.